(Re-)Installation of (Mini)Conda slow
I am not the most skilled Programmer/Computer Scientist.
So I am working on a Linux machine (Rocky 8.10). And I have had issues regarding conda environments, using python and vs code for a longer time. I somehow managed to get everything to work somehow, but now I am fed up. So setting up a fresh environment using miniforge (to use mamba in the past) and installing something (e.g. rdkit) took ages (at least overnight). Using VS Code never stopped "Finding interpreters", random "No Kernel connected", installing extensions takes for ever and so.
So first I reinstalled VS Code, but that didn't alleviate anything. Now I uninstalled miniforge and removed anything related. But again reinstalling miniconda this time is still running (stuck on executing transactions) for 4 hours now. So something is apparently not how it should be, but I do not have any clue what. Maybe you can have any ideas or point me to some things I could try. Otherwise I might need to cleanly reinstall Linux and see whether that helps.

Installing into new environment (Took virtuallly forever)
Uninstalled and reinstalled VS Code
Removed conda (miniconda and miniforge) twice
Reinstall miniconda


How performant is the system in terms of disk IO/network speed etc?

Fast.  The Root directory lies on an SSD.
